# vb .net createfile, WinUsb, must release resources?

Tags: vb.net

I have to use CreateFile imported from kernel32.dll in some VB .NET project to obtain some handle for WinUSB further functions.

The question is do I need to destroy somehow/something after CreateFile when I don't need the handle anymore?

The second question is I use WinUsb_Initialize() with CreateFile returned handle to obtain another handle for WinUSB purposes. Do I need to make some cleaning too?

Thanks in advance,

---

```
   <DllImport("kernel32.dll",
            SetLastError:=True,
            CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function CreateFile(ByVal lpFileName As String,
                                       ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Int32,
                                       ByVal dwShareMode As UInt32,
                                       ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr,
                                       ByVal dwCreationDisposition As UInt32,
                                       ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As UInt32,
                                       ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As SafeFileHandle
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll",
        CharSet:=CharSet.Auto,
        SetLasterror:=True)>
    Public Shared Function CloseHandle(ByVal Handle As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
```

Now I read somewhere if I use safehandlers in CreateFile there is no need to CloseHandle.
This is my "Disconnect" code

```
Dim ErrorStatus As Integer = 0

If hWinUSBInterface <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
    WinUsb_Free(hWinUSBInterface)
    hWinUSBInterface = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
End If

If hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then

    'hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    'RaiseEvent Error(ErrorStatus, "Disconnect")

    If CloseHandle(hDevice) Then
        hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        RaiseEvent Disconnected()
    Else
        ErrorStatus = Err.LastDllError
        RaiseEvent Error(ErrorStatus, "Disconnect")
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HANDLE` you obtained from `CreateFile()` must be released by pinvoking `CloseHandle()`.

The `WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE` you obtained from `WinUSB_Initialize()` must be released by pinvoking `WinUSB_Free()`.

Note that these requirements are spelled out in detail in the MSDN Library articles for these functions.

Comment: Indeed, I should read more carefully MSDN lib entries. Thanks for your post anyway.

Comment: A little more thing, I've done what you said and CloseHandle isn't work as expected. The handle is indeed closed since I can open a new one immediately after on the same object (usb device) but when I close the form some error appears

Comment: {"External component has thrown an exception."} and I suspect something about my imported kernel32.dll functions

Comment: This is not a forum where you can just keep asking new questions.  This is a Q+A site, one question at a time.  Click the Ask Question button when you have a new one.  And of course document it properly with at least a call stack and a snippet.